# VS 2017 crashes on Build Project/Solution with VSIX

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

We have an extension that I have upgraded from VS 2015. 
The extension creates a solution from a custom project template (which is actually just a blank library project) and loads source files from a DB.
When I try to build the solution/project VS crashes.

> "Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown."
>
> InnerException: "How can this happen?"

I'm also wondering how this can happen. It doesn't happen in VS 2015.

What do I do now? Must I report this somewhere?

Here is the CallStack for what it's worth:

```
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.StateManager.CreateBuildOnlyProjectStateSet(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project project)   Unknown
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.SynchronizeWithBuildAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace workspace, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ProjectId, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticData>> map) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.<SynchronizeWithBuildAsync>d__13>(ref Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.<SynchronizeWithBuildAsync>d__13 stateMachine)  Unknown
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.EngineV2.DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.SynchronizeWithBuildAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace workspace, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ProjectId, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticData>> map) Unknown
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzerService.SynchronizeWithBuildAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace workspace, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ProjectId, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticData>> diagnostics)  Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.SyncBuildErrorsAndReportAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzerService diagnosticService, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution solution, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ProjectId, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticData>> map) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.<SyncBuildErrorsAndReportAsync>d__24>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.<SyncBuildErrorsAndReportAsync>d__24 stateMachine)  Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.SyncBuildErrorsAndReportAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzerService diagnosticService, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution solution, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ProjectId, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticData>> map) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.OnSolutionBuild.AnonymousMethod__0()    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<OnSolutionBuild>b__0>d stateMachine) Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.TaskList.ExternalErrorDiagnosticUpdateSource.OnSolutionBuild.AnonymousMethod__0()    Unknown
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll!Roslyn.Utilities.SimpleTaskQueue.ScheduleTask.AnonymousMethod__1(System.Threading.Tasks.Task t)   Unknown
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll!Roslyn.Utilities.TaskExtensions.ContinueWithAfterDelayFromAsync.AnonymousMethod__1(System.Threading.Tasks.Task _) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>.InnerInvoke()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown
```

***UPDATE***

I have re-installed VS 2017, I have created a new vsix project in VS 2017 and copied the code across as suggested in the comments. I still get the same exception as above when I try to Build the project/solution.

Then I thought that something was wrong with my custom project template. So I bypassed the code in our extension where that is created, and hoped to create a new project in the experimental instance, add the files from the database to the newly created project in the normal way, and then build it and check whether I get the same exception.

BUT, I can't even create a new project in the experimental instance. 
I get this exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionsExplorer.UI.Aero2, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionsExplorer.UI.Aero2, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

The CallStack:

```
>   PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(object component, System.Uri resourceLocator)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionsExplorer.UI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionsExplorer.UI.VSExtensionsExplorerCtl.InitializeComponent() Unknown Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionsExplorer.UI.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionsExplorer.UI.VSExtensionsExplorerCtl.VSExtensionsExplorerCtl() Unknown Symbols loaded.
[Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
[Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(bool publicOnly, bool skipCheckThis, bool fillCache, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object[] activationAttributes, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object[] activationAttributes) Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, object[] args)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstanceCritical(System.Type type, object[] arguments)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstance(System.Type type, object[] arguments)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance(object[] arguments)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(System.Xaml.XamlType xamlType, object[] args)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(System.Xaml.XamlType xamlType, object[] args)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.CreateInstance(System.Xaml.XamlType xamlType, object[] args)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(System.Xaml.XamlMember property)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(System.Xaml.XamlReader reader) Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, bool onlyLoadOneNode, bool skipJournaledProperties, bool shouldPassLineNumberInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, System.Xaml.IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.XamlContextStack<System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlFrame> stack, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.Permissions.XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, System.Uri baseUri) Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(System.IO.Stream stream, System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext, object parent, bool closeStream)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(object component, System.Uri resourceLocator)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.NewProjectDialog.InitializeComponent()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.NewProjectDialog.NewProjectDialog(Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSNEWPROJECTDLGINFO dialogInformation, System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.NewProjectDialog.SessionState session, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetryScope<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.UserTaskEvent> userTask)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Dialogs.SVsDialogService.InvokeDialog(Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSNEWPROJECTDLGINFO dlgInfo, out string bstrLocation) Unknown Symbols loaded.
[Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
msenv.dll!InvokeNewProjectDlg(int,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned long,struct IVsBrowseProjectLocation *)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!HandleNewProjectCommand(unsigned long,unsigned long,struct tagVARIANT *,struct tagVARIANT *)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!HrShellExec(struct _GUID const *,unsigned long,unsigned long,struct tagVARIANT *,struct tagVARIANT *) Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CVSCommandTarget::ExecCmd(class CIcmdGuidCmdId const *,struct _GUID const *,unsigned long,unsigned long,struct tagVARIANT *,struct tagVARIANT *,struct _GUID *)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!`anonymous namespace'::ExecForController()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CSurfaceCommandingSupport::ExecuteForController(struct CommandUI::Models::IControllerRoot const *,unsigned long,struct tagVARIANT *,struct tagVARIANT *,struct _GUID *)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CExecuteVisitor::VisitButtonController(struct CommandUI::Models::IButtonController *,struct tagVARIANT const *,struct tagVARIANT *)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CControllerVisitorBase::DispatchVisit(struct CommandUI::Models::IControllerRoot *,struct tagVARIANT const *,struct tagVARIANT *)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CControllerVisitorBase::VisitController(struct CommandUI::Models::IControllerRoot *,struct tagVARIANT const *,struct tagVARIANT *)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CSurfaceCommandingSupport::Execute(struct CommandUI::Models::IControllerRoot *,struct tagVARIANT const *,struct tagVARIANT *) Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CommandUI::Models::Impl::CExecutableCommandElementDataSource::Execute(struct tagVARIANT const &,struct tagVARIANT *)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CommandUI::Models::Impl::CExecutableCommandElementDataSource::ExecuteVerbHandler(struct IVsUIDispatch *,unsigned short const *,struct tagVARIANT const &,struct tagVARIANT *) Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!Gel::CDataSource::Invoke(unsigned short const *,struct tagVARIANT,struct tagVARIANT *)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
[Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll!Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Invoke(string verb, object pvaIn, out object pvaOut)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.UI.Internal.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsCommand.Execute(object parameter)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource commandSource, bool userInitiated)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(object arg)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object obj)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
[Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown Symbols loaded.
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!MainMessageLoop::ProcessMessage(struct IMsoStdComponentMgr *,struct IVsWindowManager *,struct tagMSG &)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CMsoCMHandler::EnvironmentMsgLoop(void)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CMsoCMHandler::FPushMessageLoop(unsigned long)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!SCM::FPushMessageLoop(class SCMI *,unsigned long,void *)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!SCM_MsoCompMgr::FPushMessageLoop(unsigned long,unsigned long,void *)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!CMsoComponent::PushMsgLoop(unsigned long) Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!VStudioMainLogged(void)   Unknown Symbols loaded.
msenv.dll!_VStudioMain()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
devenv.exe!util_CallVsMain(struct MAINPARAM *,int *)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
devenv.exe!CDevEnvAppId::Run(unsigned short *,int)  Unknown Symbols loaded.
devenv.exe!_WinMain@16()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
devenv.exe!util_FormRootKeyPath(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short * *)    Unknown Symbols loaded.
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown Symbols loaded.
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown Symbols loaded.
```

So, why can't I create a new project in the experimental instance?

Comment: [Source of the exception](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features/Diagnostics/EngineV2/DiagnosticIncrementalAnalyzer.StateManager.cs,147). Looks like the registration of the extension is borked. Try clearing the component model cache (`%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_*\ComponentModelCache`) or a full repair of the installation. Alternatively, the VSIX may just be broken itself, either due to the upgrade not getting things quite right or wrong behavior that only happened to work by lucky coincidence in VS 2015.

Comment: You could create a default project and loads source files from a DB, then build it. If the default project template could build successful, this problem is related to your extension it self. Since it is upgrade from VS2015 version, I suggest you upgrade this extension project to VS2017 and debug it in VS2017 to check what happened in your extension.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, thanks, I'm in the process of repairing the VS 2017 installation. Clearing the model cache didn't work. Though, I suspect the upgrade might not have gone right. I'll test it and probably redo the upgrade. We intercept the Build command of VS and first do our own Build version, so theoretically I could work around this problem, but I would like the solution file after the normal VS build. And besides, something somewhere is wrong and I don't want to leave it that way.

Comment: @Wendy-MSFT, I have upgraded it to VS2017 and am debugging it in VS2017.

Comment: @Igavshne I suggest you create a new extension project in VS2017 and copy the original extension partial code to the new project. If the new project working fine, the problem is not related to VS2017 installation. And copy partial  code will help us confirm which part of code causes this problem. In addition, please check your project upgrade process based on this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Please see my updates to the post above.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?